# No Such Object available on this agent at this OID for zabbix monitoring

Tags: zabbix

I have added a `vmware` for monitoring by zabbix, Ihave added Linux by `snmp` as a template. But for some items it is showed.
No Such Object available on this agent at this `OID`

Do i add oid on `vmware`?

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 172.23.120.99 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```